# Java Web Start, invoke <installer-desc> after Java update

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Installer extension defines an application that will be run **only once**, the first time this extension **jnlp** file is used in an application.

Is there any way to invoke installer extension again if java was updated?

I'd be grateful for any kind of help. Thank you..

Comment: Why would you need to call it again?  Is the current installer putting things into the Java runtime environment extension directories?

Comment: Yes. When user will update java, the installed jars will no longer match.

Comment: *"Yes"*  Well fix that and the problem vanishes.  From [Installed Extensions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html) *"Since installed extensions extend the platform's core API, use them judiciously. They are rarely appropriate for interfaces used by a single, or small set of applications."*

Comment: Also the installer overrides the jars from security.